# The best solution to run same set of tests on two different classes

Tags: java, junit

I have two classes that are different implmentations of the same interface. 
There is also a fairly large and complicated set of unit tests to test the correctnes of implementation.

I am looking for the best way to run the same set of tests against two or possible more classes.  Unfortunately due to external constraints I am limited to using JUnit4.  So the fancy newfangled test frameworks won't work for me.

Could you suggest your favorite method of doing so without resorting to blindly copying the test into separate file and causing a maintanance headaches of keeping two files in sync.

*Clarification* : The two classes must be kept completely independent the goal is to test that both of the classes produce exactly the same output for exactly the same input.  The classes are written to the common interface.  So it is the question of how to run the same test cases against two different implementations of the same interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
public abstract class TestBase {
    private TheInterface unitToTest;

    protected abstract TheInterface getInterfaceImplementation();

    @Before
    public void setImplementation() {
         unitToTest = getInterfaceImplementation();
    }

    @Test
    public void test1 {
         //excercise and assert unitToTest
    }
}

public class ImplementationOneTest extends TestBase {
    protected TheInterface getInterfaceImplementation() {
        return new ImplementationOne();
    }
}

public class ImplementationTwoTest extends TestBase {
    protected TheInterface getInterfaceImplementation() {
        return new ImplementationTwo();
    }
}

etc.
```

Comment: Thanks... this is eactly what is needed.  I am surprised nobody asked this question before..

Answer (score 0):

You may create base test class with constructor receiving your interfaces (and test methods inside). And to concrete classes each passing some interface implementation to `super()`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Refactor common implementation into a single class (base or
   delegate).
2. Reuse current unit tests on testing refactored common
   implementation.
3. Provide specific tests where implementations differ.

If there is no common implementation details, then you MUST have different unit tests for each implementation.